# Passport JS Google OAuth20 Strategy Typescript Error

Tags: typescript, passport.js, passport-google-oauth

I'm currently migrating a passport JS Google OAuth2 strategy from JavaScript to TypeScript and I'm receiving the a TypeScript compile error. The **clientID** and **ClientSecret** fields are highlighted as having no overload matching the call. I've inspected the interface and it shows both options as string.

The full error is as follows:

TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
middleware/passport.google.ts:12:5 - error TS2769: No overload matches this call.
The last overload gave the following error.
Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.

An image of the issue can be seen here:

[image]

And the interface can be seen here:

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured this one out, just in case anyone else runs into the same issue. Unfortunately, dotenv is initially "undefined", so there are two possible solutions here:

1. Set a default value for **clientID** and **clientSecret** by setting a default string. For example:

   `const clientID: string = process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID ?? 'someDefaultString'
    const clientSecret: string = process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET ?? 'someDefaultString'`
2. Edit the passport-google-oauth20 index.d.ts file (\node_modules@types\passport-google-oauth20\index.d.ts) as follows:

   `clientID: string | undefined;
   clientSecret: string | undefined;`

I personally used the first option as I prefer not to edit node modules directly.